# Azure Fileshares on a web page hosted from a VM

Tags: azure, azure-file-share

SO, I know that Azure does not currently have a way to display FileShare data directly to a webpage. SO as a workable solution, I created a VM that hooks into the fileshare from the SMB share as a virtual drive.

I have a pipeline that generates large zip files and other smaller zips with accompanying data. The smaller zip files are about 20 Mb, and the larger zip files are in the neighborhood of ~400Gb. The ADO pipeline will upload directly to the fileshare.

The VM is using windows/IIS and cannot reference the virtual drive directly, so I have a script that copies the files to the local drive. This script will compare the virtual drive and the local drive every 10 mins; if it detects a change, I have a wait timer set for 1 hr before starting the copy, because if it starts to transfer the file before the upload is complete, the upload will error out with File in use error.

This is currently "Working" but is there another way I can do this without spending so much time just waiting?

Comment: Hi @Xolin_, In your scenario, you can utilize Azure File Sync to synchronize the files to a local drive. However, the file synchronization will only detect changes and trigger once every 24 hours. To immediately synchronize files that have changed in the Azure file share, you can run the command: Invoke-AzStorageSyncChangeDetection, for more details follow the [Azure File Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/file-sync/file-sync-deployment-guide?tabs=azure-portal,proactive-portal)

Comment: **[How long does it take for the file to sync to the servers in the sync group?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-faq?toc=/azure/storage/filesync/toc.json#afs-change-detection)**

Comment: Since you are already starting from ADO, why not run an ADO self-hosted agent on your VM? If I understand your process correctly doing so may skip some steps for you, your process could either just write to the web server VM directly or write to both the web server VM and the file share at the same time, if you need the file share for something else.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#install